# My CSS changes with the screen size

Tags: css, screen-resolution

I have seen the option of loading different css files[called responsive web designing] for different screen sizes. But I want to know if there is some other way through which I can keep the CSS uniform. 
I have to adjust the width of a title bar that should be of the same size as browser window with some margin-right

```
<toolbar width="some px value" margin-right="some px value">
```

I need some spacing at the end of the browser screen
Can I somehow get the current width of the browser screen and thus adjust my titlebar accordingly

Comment: You can always specify sizes in pixels (px).

Comment: That is the problem...... A specific pixel value may be big enough for standard screens but small for some bigger screens

Comment: I can't catch the point! :) Pixels don't work for you, percentages?

Comment: I am interested in directly getting the current browser width....and adjusting my toolbar accordingly

Comment: There are many way to do such things, show us what you have so far.

Comment: You can't do such calculations (if more complex than percentage of page size) in the CSS but you can in JavaScript, get that value in document.body.clientWidth property or, is using jQuery, via width() for the HTML body.

Comment: Yeah I guess document.body.clientWidth may work.....Thanks...
I can then dynamically keep changing the width based on the browser width....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"toolbar" defaults to being displayed as "inline". Try using "block". See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeZJs/).

But I don't think "toolbar" is a valid html tag-name (I might be wrong). In any case old versions of Internet Explorer have a hard time figuring out what to do with certain tags (like most new semantic html5 tags) and won't apply any css to them.
If you feel the need to use new semantic tags and still need legacy browser support I recomend using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). Including it at the top of your page will use a small browser hack to get support for these tags even in old browsers.